# Persistir dados em tabelas relacionadas (1 x N)

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, fluent-api

Tenho estas 2 classes relacionadas, sendo que a classe pedido tem uma Coleção de "ItensPedidos"...

A classe Pedido:

```
public class PedidoDTO
    {
        public int pedidoID { get; set; }
        public int codigo { get; set; }
        public DateTime data { get; set; }

        public int clienteID { get; set; }
        public virtual ClienteDTO Cliente { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<ItemPedidoDTO> itensPedidos { get; set; }
    }
```

E a classe ItemPedido:

```
 public class ItemPedidoDTO
    {
        public int itemPedidoID { get; set; }
        public int quantidade { get; set; }
        public decimal preco { get; set; }
        public int porcentagemDesconto { get; set; }

        public int pedidoID { get; set; }
        public virtual PedidoDTO pedido { get; set; }

        public int produdoID { get; set; }
        public virtual ProdutoDTO produto { get; set; }
    }
```

**Minha duvida é a seguinte:**
Como persisto os dados de maneira que a entidade ItemPedido receba automaticamente a chave estrangeira?

---

*No projeto faço uso de: Code first, EF6, migrations, repositórios genéricos,  repositórios de implementação e mapeamento com Fluent Api.*

Answer (score 1):

Márcio, eu trabalho com Entity Framework Core, existe uma certa diferença mas creio que pode te ajudar a resolver seu problema. Contudo, considere utilizar o EF Core, principalmente se for um novo projeto. Veja mais informações de comparação dos dois [aqui](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/efcore-and-ef6/).

Primeira questão a considerar é o mapeamento (*não mapeei todos os campos*):

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<PedidoDTO> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("Pedido");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.pedidoId);
    builder.Property(x => x.pedidoId).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    builder.HasMany(x => x.itensPedidos).WithOne(x => x.pedido).HasForeignKey(x => x.pedidoId).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
}
```

No mapeamento do item do pedido você não deve referenciar o pedido, pois o pedido já fez essa relação:

```
public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<ItemPedidoDTO> builder)
{
    builder.ToTable("ItemPedido");
    builder.HasKey(x => x.itemPedidoID);
    builder.Property(x => x.itemPedidoID).IsRequired().ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    builder.Property(x => x.pedidoID).IsRequired();
}
```

Feito mapeamento corretamente, a inserção é simples, você pode inserir o pedido diretamente:

```
var pedido = new PedidoDTO()
{
    clienteId = 1,
    itensPedidos = new List<ItemPedidoDTO>
    {
       new ItemPedidoDTO()
       {
           produtoId = 10,
           quantidade = 5M,
       }),
    }
};

context.PedidoDTO.Add(pedido);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Bom, observe que os casos do `cliente` e do `produto` eu informei somente o id de cada. Se você adicionar a entidade o EF vai tentar inserí-la também. Para que isto não aconteça você deve fazer um `Attach` na entidade para que o Entity a reconheça. Ou simplesmente deixe-a como `null` que irá funcionar.

A resposta segue [essa](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/ef/core/saving/related-data) orientação. Quando eu fiz um teste no meu cenário eu me deparei com o problema do relacionamento que descrevi acima, corrigido isso funcionou normalmente.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Eu não sei se é necessário mapear a entidade estrangeira (`ItemPedidoDTO`) à entidade dependente (`PedidoDTO`). Basta que `PedidoDTO` tenha uma agregação `ICollection<ItemPedidoDTO>` virtual e pública.

Comment: @MarceloShinitiUchimura realmente não deve precisar. Mas eu prefiro mapear para ficar claro, principalmente para informar ao banco como irá trabalhar a chave estrangeira, nesse exemplo eu coloquei o "OnDelete Cascade".